# regex issue with '?' in matching routes

Tags: regex, pcre, vercel

I am trying to match routes on now-zeit deployment using PCRE regex:

```
"/song/(.*)feed=(?<feedValue>[^&]+)&PzID=(?<itunesIdValue>[^&]+)"
```

Although `"song/?feed=random&PzID=863"` does work but 
`"song/RANDOMSLUGNAME?feed=random&PzID=863"` gives the 404 error page. I am new to regex. Can anyone please tell me if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Your regex [seems to work well](https://regex101.com/r/X2744C/1).

Comment: yeah that's the thing. It works well when I check online but when I deploy to zeit-now, it seems to fail. So not sure if it's a zeit-now issue.

Comment: I was able to resolve it. It was a zeit-now issue. The query params are forwarded by default. So I just needed to do "/song/(.*)" to match the main url.

Comment: You may post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve it. It was a zeit-now issue. The query params are forwarded by default. So I just needed to do "/song/(.*)" to match the main url.